# Revert revision for Google Drive Spreadsheet using API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am required to provide revision-revert functionality for Google Drive Spreadsheet (Without losing revision history).

As far as [v4 SpreadSheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) doesn't have revision functionality. I am trying to use [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/). I can successfully get revisions list with this API and get the specific revision.

But I can't find a way to roll back file on the target revision. Is there the way to do this using Google API calls?

Answer (score 0):

`Revisions.list` is used to get the versions list. To actually go to the version, use [revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get). You will be asked to provide a `revisionId` (which you obtained from revisions.list).

You can use [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get#try-it) to do that.

Comment: Yes, I am able to get a specific revision of the file as I've described in the question. 
The problem here to replace the original file with the old one without losing revision history.

Comment: what you mean replace? did u use revisions.get?